# Is there a way to emulate the 'multiple cursor' features of Sublime Text in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sublimetext2, visual-studio-express

Is there a way to emulate the 'multiple cursor' features of Sublime Text in Visual Studio?

I'm aware that you can use ST2 as your external editor in Visual Studio, but I'm not sure this is possible in the Express Edition.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Check out [this new Visual Studio add-on which brings exactly what you want](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SimultaneousEditingForVisualStudioWithTheFreeMultiEditExtension.aspx), It supports all versions of Visual Studio since 2010.

[image: Showing multi edit in VS]

Since Visual Studio  Express doesn't support add-ins, there is no way to enable this feature on the express version.

Comment: FYI, its not just for 2012 as of now.

Comment: @Terrance given the tags of the OP, he's looking for VS2010 support, not for 2013. But I've updated the post to reflect the availibility of the 2013 version.

Comment: its supported in 2010 as well. I know it does not show in the link of supported (and apparently I can't even filter by vs2010 anymore for some reason) but it is in the 2010 extension list and is working as I have just installed it on vs2010 last night. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336135.aspx

Comment: Something I often want to do is select a whole load of property names and copy them somewhere. They don't line up so I can't use alt+drag selection, what I'd like to do is use alt+drag, then ctrl+shift+left, ctrl+shift+right to select the single words (property names) on each line... (there's probably a 'select word under cursor' shortcut) at the moment I'd have to switch to SublimeText to do that :(

Answer (score 7):

Update! In VS 2019 we can use `ctrl+alt+click`. Also, it brings the old block selection (`alt+mouse selection`) and other options like the ones in `Edit>Multiple Insertion Symbols`.

Comment: In my current installation of VS 2019, the menu entry is called Edit>Multiple Carets.

Comment: you know how hard it is find this? Google, Bing, all of them keep talking about VS Code or the alt+click that only does contiguous carets. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The only real Sublime Text equivalent is [MixEdit](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f301cf82-e80b-4b92-9e5c-ef7985ae6702).

[image]

It is not free though. [You can buy it for $9](http://www.codinglabs.net/BuyMixEdit.aspx), and that's a once-in-a-lifetime-payment.

You can use this [quick guide](http://www.codinglabs.net/MixEdit.aspx) but, if you're coming from Sublime, commands are very intuitive.

UPDATE: Don't want to pay? Just realized you can click <*cancel*> whenever prompted to register.

Comment: How can I activate MixEdit (Explicit CTRL+Click) for other types than txt?

Answer (score 2):

There's another extension called [*MixEdit*](http://www.codinglabs.net/MixEdit.aspx) that offers more features than *MultiEdit* but is [commercial](http://www.codinglabs.net/BuyMixEdit.aspx) with a trial version.

*(I have no relation to the author)*

Comment: But this is only for the text Editor. Can’t activate CTRL+Click to set multiple Cursors in any other type except .txt :\

Answer (score 0):

VS Community 2019

`shift + alt + .` for next match

`shift + alt + ;` for all matches